# Dotnetnuke module communication problem

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I have a problem with the dnn module communication. I have a module that implements the module communication interface both listener and sender. in this module, I have a placeholder where I load a new ascx control.  the problem is when I want to Communicate from this new dynamically loaded control. In this control i also implemented  module communication interfaces( listener and sender). but when I call sender method, in this dynamic loaded control to update an other module (on same page)nothing happens. But then i call a " sender " from the dynamic loaded controls container control( the control where i have the placeholder) it works updating the other module on the same page. It seams that module comunications do not work in dynamic loaded ascx controls at all. 
Is there anyone who have any idea , to solve this
/theonealf

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it's a timing issue.  Try loading your dynamic control in the `Init` event, and see if it will catch the communication being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @bdukes, Also there are additional things that I would recommend to check:

1. Check if there is any exception while nothing happens
2. Does your control inherits from PortalModuleBase? This will be required if you want to use moduleId, UserInfo, PortalId or any other dnn specific objects.

There can be other checks but it depends on your answer by trying above and @bdukes suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have had limited success with the communications interface. If you can get to work for your needs, then excellent. In case you find you need another solution, here's what I've done:

If I understand the question correctly, you're concerned with the specific use-case where one module needs to communicate with another module during the loading of a page. If that is so, you most likely have one module which is the one that needs to communicate, and one or more modules which need to pick up that communication.

I've used `Context.Items` in combination with the ASP.NET life cycle to solve this problem. The `Items` collection is just a bag that anything can be stuffed into or pulled out of. The module that needs to communicate can put things into that item bag during `Page_Load`:

```
var item = "My Thing";
Context.Items.Add("MyThingKey", item);
```

The modules which need to consume that thing can pull things out of that bag during `PreRender`.

```
var item = Context.Items["MyThingKey"].ToString();
```

The key is doing this during PreRender. This way, you are assured that the consuming of the communication happens *after* the production of the communication.

Good luck!